# 1084: Syntax error: expecting in before colon

Tags: actionscript-3, syntax-error

Error message:

> Scene 1, Layer 'Script', Frame 1, Line 11, Column 13   1084: Syntax error: expecting in before colon.

```
var tab:Array = new Array();

tab[0] = {alder:45, navn: "N Linjesæter"};

tab[1] = {alder:34, navn: "P Kurverud"};

tab[2] = {alder:18, navn: "O Sirkelstad"};

tab[3] = {alder:12, navn: "J Rektangelsen"};

tab[4] = {alder:27, navn: "M Ellipsen"};

var utskrift:String = "";

for(var teller:int = 0;teller < 3; teller ++)

{
    for(varNavn:String in tab[teller])

    {
        utskrift = utskrift + varNavn + ": " +

        tab[teller] [varNavn] + "\n";
    }
    utskrift = utskrift + "\n";
}

txtFelt.text = utskrift;
```

What have i done wrong here? I simply can't find it.

Comment: You specified a type for a variable, but you can only do so if you are _declaring_ the variable. I think you have a typo, so try `var Navn:String` instead of `varNavn:String` in the `for` statement. Reference: [Looping](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7fcf.html)

Answer (score 2):

I think you have a typo.

This:

```
for(varNavn:String in tab[teller])
```

Needs to be changed to this:

```
for(var Navn:String in tab[teller])
```

Or if you really needed a variable named `varNavn` then use:

```
for(var varNavn:String in tab[teller])
```